# Wireless dongle driver don't work(Debian)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, debian, wifi-driver

I have a WiFi dongle that said to support GNU/Linux, however no drivers were found on the CD, after hours of research i found this https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb and installed the driver, I'm pretty sure my device is listed as supported, but the device is still not recognized, it is listed on lsusb command, but not recognized by any WiFi program like WiFi Radar and wireless-tools, also when i use the iwconfig command, this is what i see http://pastebin.com/Z11QfP2N i really need this wireless connection working, can you help, please?